# Как авторизоваться при парсинге в всплывающем окне аутентификации?

Tags: java, android

[image: Всплывающее окно Alert для авторизации на сайте]

Возможно как либо авторизоваться через клиентскую часть на сайте для парсинга? При нажатии на кнопку "Личный кабинет" на сайте вылезает всплывающее окно и дальше идей как реализовать авторизацию нет.

> Парсил через библиотеку jsoup в Android studio

Comment: что означает фраза "Парсил через библиотеку jsoup в Android studio"?

Comment: Как было в статье, подключаем библиотеку jsoup и парсим сайт (Скачиваем сайт и достаём нужную информацию)

Comment: очень оптимистично думать, что все знают, о какой статье речь. И каким образом туда вдруг "подключаем библиотеку jsoup". Не говоря уже о том, что АС это не инструмент для парсинга сайтов и почему оно тут используется вообще непонятно.

Comment: Возможно, на том сайте пройдет basic auth: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization . Погуглил это по jsoup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680083/5909792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Спасибо ***gil9red*** за помощь

```
String username = "LOGIN";
String password = "PASSWORD";
String login = username + ":" + password;
String url = "Link";
        
String base64login = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(login.getBytes());
Document docWebSite = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login).get();
```